# Steps Menu Not Displaying in Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-components

Trying out primeng to learn, I modified the cli generated starter code as below.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {StepsModule,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    name: string; 

    message1: string;

    private items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {label: 'Step 1'},
            {label: 'Step 2'},
            {label: 'Step 3'}
        ];
    }

    onClick() {
        this.message1 = 'Hello ' + this.name;
    }
}
```

app.component.html thus:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" pInputText>
<button type="button" pButton label="Click" icon="fa fa-check" (click)="onClick($event)"></button>

<div>{{message1}}</div>
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="http://localhost/"></p-fileUpload>


<p-steps [model]="items" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>
```

app.module.ts thus:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { InputTextModule, ButtonModule }  from 'primeng/primeng';
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {StepsModule,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InputTextModule, 
    ButtonModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    StepsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It displays this almost blank screen with no console errors:

[image]

When I remove the p-steps tag, it shows the other elements correctly

[image]

What am I getting wrong with respect to the p-steps?

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: none whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **'MenuItem'** from imports. when I added MenuItem in app.module.ts I got a compilation error.

Error : 'MenuItem' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Importing it in the component only should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** Added StepsModule from wrong reference.

**Try add:**
import {StepsModule} from '**primeng/steps**';

**Remove:**
import {StepsModule,**MenuItem**} from **'primeng/primeng'**; (AppModule)